why the vertical align doesnt work in css
why doesn't the vertical align :middle work in my code even that i changed the display into inlineblock
shouldnt the xo text be in the middle vertically of that container
when does it actually work?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
 .container {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: pink;
}

.centered {
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}


</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="centered">xo</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


"shouldnt the xo text be in the middle vertically of that container?". No, because that's not what vertical-align: middle does.

remove centered css and modify .container {     height: 100px;     background-color: pink;     display: flex;     justify-content:center;    align-items:center; }
